# Get header file paths for certain c file in IAR NXP compiler

Tags: arm, iar, nxp-microcontroller

I'm compiling a c file from CMD using NXP compiler and adding to the command include directories with -I flag, is there a way to print out the paths of headers files that where used for compiling?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you add --dependencies flag to command